# Modifying the target of a Lens conditionally

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I have a function that produces an updated board from an input and a board, if the move is permitted by the rules of the game:

```
move :: Input -> Board -> Maybe Board
```

The board is wrapped in the `GameState` type with some additional data:

```
type GameState = (Board, ...)
```

Now I'd like to use lenses to update the board in the game state if `move` yields `Just` a value.
I can do this with a helper function:

```
updateGameState :: Input -> GameState -> GameState
updateGameState input gs = gs & _1 %~ (f $ move input)
  where
    f g x = maybe x id (g x)
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a combinator that modifies the target of a
`Lens` only if the supplied function returns a `Just`. I've found the `?~` operator, but that handles partiality on the left hand side.

Is there a (likely more general) combinator that can achieve this, or is there another way to express this in a terse and idiomatic way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Maybe

updateGameState :: Input -> GameState -> GameState
updateGameState input = fromMaybe <*> _1 (move input)
-- updateGameState x s = fromMaybe s $ _1 $ move x
```

This uses the fact that `Lens s t a b` is a type alias for `forall f . Functor f => (a -> f b) -> (s -> f t)`, so we can choose to use `Maybe` as `f` and get a function of type `GameState -> Maybe GameState`.

Comment: Thanks. The `Applicative` instance of `(->) r` and this `fromMaybe <*> f` idiom is what I've been looking for.